# Is there any sources which provides API for video recording?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, multimedia

I need an source which gives the video recording and a submit button, but not one to one interaction.
I have gone through some sites but they are providing video conferencing, the video recording source can be pricing or free.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I did some research and found this site: OpenTok, now part of Vonage.

https://www.vonage.com/communications-apis/video/pricing/